# Mysqli fetch array warning, unable to debug

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, swiftmailer

I am trying to debug a newsletter mailing script for a project I am working on. This used to work perfectly fine with PHP Mailer, however I ended up changing my mailer to Swift Mailer and since I have been having the most bizarre problem.

I keep getting the following warning, after the first iteration of the while loop (one e-mail is sent out to the first e-mail address in the mysql result set, then I get this warning):

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, integer given in /home1/username/public_html/domain/newslettermailer.php on line 15
```

This is my newlettrmailer.php script:

```
   include('inc/connect.inc.php');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `newsletter`";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

    $status = Array();

    require('mailer/swift_required.php');


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $email =  $row['email'];

        echo $email . " GOOD<br/>";

      // Create the Transport
      $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.domain.com', 25)
      ->setUsername('support@domain.com')
      ->setPassword('password');

      // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        $mailTo = Array();
        $mailTo[] = $email;  


    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Newsletter Test!')
      ->setFrom(array('support@domain.com' => 'Subject'))
      ->setTo($mailTo);

    $body = '<strong style="text-decoration:underline;">Test</strong>';
      $message->setBody($body,'text/html');


          // Send the message
        $result = $mailer->send($message);



        if($result==0)
        { //MESSAGE FAILED
            $status .= $email . ': <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Fail</span><br/>';
        }
        else
        { //SUCCESS!
            $status .= $email . ': <span style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">Success!</span><br/>';
        }

    }
```

While trying to debug, I modified the script above to the following, and got not errors and no warnings what so ever, and all e-mails printed out:

```
         include('inc/connect.inc.php');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `newsletter`";

        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

        $status = Array();

        require('mailer/swift_required.php');


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo $row['email'] . '<br/>';

        }
```

I have been trying to debug this for quite a while now and am really having a difficult time with this, I appreciate any suggestions as to why this is happening.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're reusing the variable `$result`:

```
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

So on the second iteration of the `while` loop, it's trying to pass that to `mysqli_fetch_array()` instead of the result return from `mysqli_query()`.

Use a different variable for this second result.

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply. I appreciate it! This indeed was the problem :)

Comment: Since the problem happens on the 2nd iteration, the obvious thing to look for is an assignment to the variable within the loop, isn't it?

Comment: Wasn't so obvious for me, although it should of been, you're right. For some reason I thought it was mysql related.

Comment: That's why you should read error messages carefully. This one tells you exactly what went wrong -- somehow $result changed from being a mysqli_result to an integer. And since it was OK on the first iteration, mysqli_query must have been successful.